# Why Intersect method is not working as per expectation?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have written this:

```
public class AnagramEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        var t = x.Intersect(y).Count();
        return t == x.Length;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I would like to find Anagrams words inside my List, so I have used the above `IEqualityComparer` like this:

```
List<string> inputList = new List<string>() { "eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat" };
var result =  inputList.GroupBy(w => w, new AnagramEqualityComparer());
```

The result should be three groups, but it seems it will return 6 groups, each group containing one item. So does anybody know, why my `Intersect` method isn't working inside comparer as per expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the `Intersect` call. When comparing two objects with an `IEqualityComparer`, they are first hashed and the hashes compared, and only if they are equal `Equals` is called.

A string's `GetHashCode` is based on the characters in it and their order, so anagrams could (and probably would) have different hash codes. Instead, you should have a hash code that's agnostic to the charatcers' order. You could sort the characters in the string and then hash it, but that would make the calculation so slow (relatively), that it would negate the point of hashing. One simple idea could be to use the string's length:

```
public class AnagramEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        var t = x.Intersect(y).Count();
        return t == x.Length;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.Length;
    }
}
```